# Align div to top with all other boxes

Tags: css, css-float

Hey all here are my tables i have placed in a DIV for each.

[image: float issue]

The CSS code for this is:

```
#PackageBG1 {
      position:relative;
      width:218px;
      z-index:10;
      top: 30px;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    #PackageBG2 {
      position:relative;
      width:218px;
      z-index:10;
      top: 30px;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    #PackageBG3 {
      position:relative;
      width:218px;
      z-index:10;
      top: 30px;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    #PackageBG4 {
      position:relative;
      width:218px;
      z-index:10;
      top: 30px;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
```

The layout for the boxes are:

```
<div id="PackageBG1">
<table id="PackageOne" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="0" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/mobileit-design-work-MOBILEITINC3_03.jpg" width="215" height="10" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-image: url(images/mobileit-design-work-MOBILEITINC3_11.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-y; background-position:left top;" width="3px"></td>
        <td style="background-image: url(images/mobileit-design-work-MOBILEITINC3_12.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:#ececec;">
            <div id="Package">
              <div id="playIcon">
                <img src="images/playIcon_53.png" width="28" height="24" />
              </div>
              <span class="packageTitle">Virtual Desktop</span>
              <span class="packageTitle-sub">Standard Package 1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="packages-text"><p>
              - Enter text here<br>
              - About<br>
              - Pkg<br>
              - Enter text here<br>
              - About<br>
              - Pkg <br>
              - Pkg <br>
              - another<br>
              - and another<br>
              - Pkg <br>
              - another<br>
              - and another<br>
              - another<br>
              - and another<br>              
              - and again
              </p></div>
            <span class="packages-price">$29.95</span><span class="packages-text-bold"> /month</span><br>
            </p>
            <div id="Package-ON"><img src="images/ordernow_55.png" width="133" height="35"></div>        
        </td>
        <td style="background-image: url(images/mobileit-design-work-MOBILEITINC3_13.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-y; background-position:right top;" width="3px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/mobileit-design-work-MOBILEITINC3_23.jpg" width="215" height="10" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
          </div>
```

I am trying to get the second table to align with both the left and right tables when it doesn't have as much text as the others do.

**Heres the JDFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/RBq3a/2/ **

Comment: can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `vertical-align:top` to your TD. Write like this:

```
td,th {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/RBq3a/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: absolute; top: 0;` to the content of the boxes (the tables). *EDIT:* Tables are block elements, so I believe `vertical-align:top;` is the correct attribute.

Comment: Doesn't move the box at all. Still in the same position when adding **vertical-align:top;** to all 4 boxes.

Comment: Don't add it to the box, add it to the table element's CSS. #PackageOne{
      vertical-align:top;
    }

Comment: Still nothing. JSFiddle posted in OP.

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to you center boxed..

Comment: Doesn't move the box at all. Still in the same position when adding **vertical-align:top;** to all 4 boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Your #PackageBG2, #PackageBG2, #PackageBG3, #PackageBG4 have exactly the same code, so should be move to a class .packageBG. For your problem, try this:

```
.packageBG {
  position:relative;
  width:218px;
  display: inline-block; //made your element display inline
  vertical-align: top; //made your element align top
  z-index:10;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Apply these attribute to all your elements